# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}/a_n,$ where the $a_1>0$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n+1/(a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Let $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence with such properties

$$a_1>0,\quad a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n}.$$

Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.

Could you please verify whether my approach and solution attempt is correct? If there is a better way how to approach this question, I'll gladly appreciate any of your ideas.

My attempt:

It follows from the properties of the given sequence that $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is a positive and purely increasing sequence, ie.

$a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n<na_n$.

We get

$a_{n+1}>a_n+\frac{1}{na_n}\implies a_{n+1}>a_1+\frac{1}{a_n}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n})$.

Suppose that the sequence $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is limited before $M\in\mathbb{R}$, then

$1+\frac{1}{a_n}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n})$

is limited.

It follows that

$1+\frac{1}{M}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n})$

is limited, which is a contradiction.

Thus, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$. Since $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1+\frac{1}{a_n(a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n)}$, we get $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$.

Comment: I think you want the initial condition  $a_1>0$.

Comment: You can eliminate the summation by rewriting the recurrence relation as $a_{n+1}(a_{n+2} - a_{n+1})(a_{n+1} - a_n) = (a_{n+1} - a_n) - (a_{n+2} - a_{n+1})$, $a_2 = a_1 + \frac{1}{a_1}$.  I'm not sure if this makes things much easier, though.

Comment: You are approach is correct. I think however, that a more direct solution is possible: Assuming $a_1>0$, then $a_n$ is increasing and so, $\sum^\infty_{j=1}a_n=\infty$ (why?).
Notice that $$1\leq \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1+\frac{1}{a_n\sum^n_{j=1}a_j}\leq 1+\frac{1}{a_1\sum^n_{j=1}a_j}$$